# Matching numbers with multi dimensional arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, for-loop, multidimensional-array

How could I write a function where it checks if any of the rows of `Nums`: `{1, 2, 3} {4, 5, 6} {1, 5, 9}` are valid within `Val1-6`. For example in `Val2` which contains `{5, 9, 1}` has elements that are within the 3rd row of `Nums` which includes `{1, 5, 9}`. `Val6` would also be valid since the number `1, 2, 3` is also within the first row of `Nums`. The only values that should not pass for the function should be `Val 3-5` since those arrays don't contain all the elements of each row in `Nums`. For a Val array to pass as true it has to contain all 3 numbers within a single row in `Nums`. The function below is faulty how could I fix it to work as intended.

Function:

```
int match_arrays(int *arr1, int *arr2, int len) {
  for (int p = 0; p < len; p++) {
    if (arr1[p] != arr2[p]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Main function

```
int main()
{

    int Val1[3] = {1, 5, 9};
    int Val2[3] = {5, 9, 1};
    int Val3[2] = {1, 2}
    int Val4[3] = {4, 5, 4};
    int Val5[3] = {4, 4, 4};
    int Val6[5] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 3};
    int count;
    int Nums[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 5, 9}}
    for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
      if (match_arrays(Val1, Nums[p], 3)) {
        printf("Val1 valid \n");
        }
      else if (match_arrays(Val2, Nums[p], 3)) {
        printf("Val2 valid \n");
        }
      else if (match_arrays(Val3, Nums[p], 2)) {
        printf("Val3 valid \n");
        }
      else if (match_arrays(Val4, Nums[p], 3)) {
        printf("Val4 valid \n");
        }
      else if (match_arrays(Val5, Nums[p], 3)) {
        printf("Val5 valid \n");
        }
      else if (match_arrays(Val6, Nums[p], 5)) {
        printf("Val6 valid \n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Val1 valid
Val2 valid
Val6 valid
```

Comment: I have no idea what `winning_order[p]` is - shouldn't you be passing `Nums` to `match_arrays`?  But be careful of the lengths passed to `match_arrays`  -  `Val3` only has two items but you pass a three and then index into a spot that doesn't exist in `Val3`.

Comment: sorry about that it was supposed to be Nums intead

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your match_arrays() function checks the first element of Nums[p] against the first element of ValX, and so on.  But that doesn't take into account if they are in a different order.  So to check if every value in Nums[p] exists somewhere inside ValX you need nested loops.

Also, match_arrays() needs to take two sizes - one for Nums[p] and one for ValX.  I guess you could hardcode the size of Nums[p] since it is the same for every row of Nums - but what if it wasn't?

I would write it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int contains(int *Val, int ValSize, int Num)
{
    int ReturnValue = 0;
    // Check if Val contains Num
    for (int p = 0; p < ValSize; p++)
        if (Val[p] == Num)
            ReturnValue = 1;
    // Return whether Val contained Num
    return ReturnValue;
}

int match_arrays(int *Val, int ValSize, int *NumsRow, int NumsRowSize)
{
    int ReturnValue = 0;
    // Check if Val contains all the elements of NumsRow
    for (int p = 0; p < NumsRowSize; p++)
        if (contains(Val, ValSize, NumsRow[p]))
            ReturnValue++;
    // Return whether Val contained all the elements of NumsRow
    return (ReturnValue==NumsRowSize);
}

int main()
{
    int Val1[3] = {1, 5, 9};
    int Val2[3] = {5, 9, 1};
    int Val3[2] = {1, 2};
    int Val4[3] = {4, 5, 4};
    int Val5[3] = {4, 4, 4};
    int Val6[5] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 3};

    int Nums[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 5, 9}};

    for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
        if (match_arrays(Val1, /* elements of Val1 = */ 3, Nums[p], /* elements of Nums[p] = */ 3)) {
            printf("Val1 valid at Num[%d] \n", p);
        }
        if (match_arrays(Val2, 3, Nums[p], 3)) {
            printf("Val2 valid at Num[%d] \n", p);
        }
        if (match_arrays(Val3, 2, Nums[p], 3)) {
            printf("Val3 valid at Num[%d] \n", p);
        }
        if (match_arrays(Val4, 3, Nums[p], 3)) {
            printf("Val4 valid at Num[%d] \n", p);
        }
        if (match_arrays(Val5, 3, Nums[p], 3)) {
            printf("Val5 valid at Num[%d] \n", p);
        }
        if (match_arrays(Val6, 5, Nums[p], 5)) {
            printf("Val6 valid at Num[%d] \n", p);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/wtPcHTk2Z